Movie where police officer kidnaps, man ties him up and torments him
I'm looking for an American film that I would say is from the last 20 years.
A white Police officer (or actor/makeup artist I cannot quite remember) kidnaps a man because the man tries to rob him or something similar. He ties him up and shows polaroid pictures of other victims he has kidnapped beaten up and bruised.
But what the guy tied up does not know is that the police officer used make up on them in the polaroid pictures (as he is an actor also in the movie I think) and it wasn't real - he is just doing it to scare his victims
The police officer does it because in the movie it looks like he has tortured hundreds of people and taken photos of them because he has used make up. He then kidnaps other people shows them the photos to scare them and gets a buzz out of it, drugs them up and torments them by pretending he is going to torture them.
There is also a scene, I think, where the officer is having a party in one room and the man is tied up in another and he try's to escape. He goes through a sliding glass door and there is a swimming pool. The man has been drugged so he is dopey. A lady neighbour sees them and the officer says that he is drunk and takes him back into his house.

The Perfect Host

An on-the-run convict looking for temporary cover finds it at the house of a very colorful character. 

-


A neighbour of Warwick, a prying old lady (whom John also tried to trick into letting him into her house earlier) hears John moaning and goes over to investigate. Warwick is able to trick her into leaving, blaming a drunk dinner guest for the noise
John's body is left outside with the trash. He wakes up and discovers that most of his injuries are fake; Warwick is a master of movie makeup. L.A.P.D. Detective Morton (Nathaniel Parker) arrives at Warwick's door – Warwick is actually a police lieutenant






YOU ARE AMAZING!!!!! Thank you SSOOOOO much I can finally sleep.Thanks to everyone for your help

Glad I could help! If you want you can accept the answer by clicking on the check mark beside it.
